# Regex two special characters in a row

Tags: regex

I have this regex
`\[.+\]\(.+\)`

Why does it match this string entirely?

```
[test1](test1) thisbitshouldnotmatch [test2](test2)
```

It should only match `[test1](test1)` and `[test2](test2)`. `thisbitshouldnotmatch` should not match.

Comment: What makes you think that it should only match `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: Sorry I worded the question better. I think the stuff between the second square bracket and first round bracket should not match.

Comment: *Off topic*: If your regex flavor supports recursive pattern `(?R)` you may try the following `(?:\[(?:[^[\]]|(?R))*\]|\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\))`, this would even match strings like `[test1[test11]](test1(test11))` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uP7kE2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this expression:

```
\[.+?\]\(.+?\)
```

That will limit the result so it only matches the *first* occurrence of `[]` and of `()`. Notice that by default an expression such as this: `.+` will try to match as much of the input as possible. By adding a `?` quantifier at the end: `.+?` we're specifying that the search should stop at the first match it finds.

Answer (score 7):

That is because the `+` operator is **greedy**.

For expression `\[.+\]\(.+\)` the characters are matched as follows:

```
[test1](test1) thisbitshouldnotmatch [test2](test2)
[..........................................](.....)
```

so, whole input matches!

You'd need to either use nongreedy:

```
\[.+?\]\(.+?\)
```

Or, explicitery disallow some characters

```
\[[^\]]+\]\([^)]+\)
```

(notice how I replaced the catch-any `.` with a character group that excludes `]` or `)` respectively)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the dot lazy otherwise it will grab *everything* it can:

```
\[.+?]\(.+?\)
```

Or, even better, use a negated character class, so a `[` followed by many `not ]` followed by a `]`

```
\[[^]]++]\([^)]++\)
```

Also note that you don't need to escape `]`

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but what is the exact meaning of `++` here? "even more greedy"? I don't think I've met any `++` operator before, as it would essentially be the same as plain `+`. Which regex dialect is that?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes, in a sense - it's _possessive_. The way the regex engine works is by processing one char at a time. If the pattern is greedy (like `.*`) the engine will grab everything that matches first then _backtrack_ until the whole pattern matches. If the pattern is lazy (like `.*?`) then the engine will grab one char at a time until the whole pattern doesn't match. So the greedy/lazy distinction is to do with which _end_ the engine matches from. A possessive pattern grabs _everything_ the matches and **never** backtracks. Hence it can be much faster.

Comment: Disabling backtracking makes much sense. I know it from .Net/C# Regex engine (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.80).aspx) in form of operator `?>` as in `a(?>[bc]*)d` and but never seen in `++` form. Thanks!